# What regex pattern should I use to find two strings with similar value on successive lines

Tags: regex, vim, vi

What regex pattern should I use to find two strings with a similar value on successive lines

For example, if I have something like:

(NOTE: the following values are already indented in the front)

```
    end
    end
```

how would I search for this using the **vi** editor?

EDIT

```
I would like it to match "    end" and "    end" or "  end" and "  end"
```

Comment: Please find in the forum of vi editor

Comment: @diEcho - I thought this was a forum to ask questions, why should I go elsewhere. Why there is a down vote on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned that the values are indented... you can use this pattern to overcome that issue:

`/end\n\s*end`

The `\s` stands for whitespace, meaning it can be either a tab or a space. The `*` means there can be none or infinite of the preceding character (in this case, whitespace). If you wanted to just match two spaces you could use `/end\n  end` or `/end\n\s\send`. If you want to match four you could similarly type them all out or do `/end\n\s\{4}end` to only match 4 whitespace characters (space or tab).

I think what you'd really like to do is match identical lines. So you can do `/\(^.*$\)\n\1` to accomplish that. If you want a certain number of identical lines you could do `/\(^.*$\)\(\n\1\)\{15}` (this example uses 15 but you can change that to any number you'd like or switch `\{15}` with `*` for any matches.

Comment: Thanks for the above tip, the above matches "    end" (4 spaces) and the line below as "  end" (2 spaces). I just modified the question which shows what I need, sorry if I wasn't clear

Comment: Okay, I updated my answer - hope that's what you're looking for.

Comment: priya: Your comment isn't clear either. Would you like to only match identical lines (including indentation) or, as in the topoc title, similar lines?

Comment: match identical lines (including indentation). also do note that certain lines might have 4 spaces before or 2 spaces before or 10 spaces before.

Comment: If you want to match identical lines you can use my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty straightforward:

```
/pattern\npattern/
```

Where `pattern` is whatever you want to find. Your question is too vague for a more useful answer.

Comment: Consider also the `^\(pat\)\n\1` pattern.

Comment: @ib. I have, but the OP said "similar strings". Using `\1` would only match equal strings.